# ServletOutputStream byte array to pdf corrupt pdf

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets, struts, outputstream

I use tomcat 7.0.53, Struts 1.2.7, Spring 3.1.1. This is my code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\pdf\\" + report.getFileName());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(report.getData());
fos.close();

response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "application; filename="
                    + report.getFileName());
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(report.getData().length);

ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(report.getData());
outputStream.flush();
```

The file I get is right no problem there. But the file I get from response is corrupted. I tried to set encoding to response, tried to turn on spring CharacterEncodingFilter, tomcats SetCharacterEncodingFilter. Nothing helps. Where should I look at?
p.s. this code is in Struts Action execute method

Comment: Did you try to close your output stream at the end?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but read somewhere that I shouldn't close it in struts action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to return a null instead of an ActionForward so Struts knows the response was handled within the action.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to save the result that you get from your webserver and compare it with the correct pdf. This way you'll see if there are some extra bytes at beginning or end, differences in encoding or whatever else is different.

Comment: There are some differences in normal pdf and what I got from response, the biggest is that i got full html of the page from which I get it. Don't know why it's there and what to do.

Comment: Then it depends on where the code that you quote is located. If struts renders the output itself, you'll just add to it (e.g. when the content you have above is in a JSP). outputStream.close() might help, unless you see the HTML before the PDF. In that case, move the code from UI (view, jsp) to the action handler

Comment: `outputStream.close()` didn't help. This code is in Struts Action execute method, what do you mean by move from UI? If I understood right this is the action handler already.

Comment: found an answer. I needed to return null instead of an action forward. it seems to be so obvious..

Comment: ouch - now that you say it, I remember. It's been a while since I last *actively* used struts 1.2 (though funny enough, I'm still in *passive* contact with that framework). Good to know that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove response.setContentLength(report.getData().length); and try if it works, by doing this you also enable chunked data transmission.

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar issue - corrupted binary pic. upon the download.
Then while downloading TXT/XML files,  I have noticed few blank lines at the beginning the text body.

Using the suggestion above on JSP, I removed all line breaks in my JSP page which manages the download. 
So all jsp and server tags follow in one single line:

```
<jsp:useBean.. ><%..response.  ;response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_RESET_CONTENT);return; %>
```

This removed extra blank lines in TXT/XML and solved binary corruption issue as well.

Olaf, thank you for the clue